# How to read an indefinite number of variables from scanf (separated by space or new lines)

Tags: c, scanf

I want to write a program that reads an arbitrary number of positive integer values from stdin (separated by new lines or space) and outputs the corresponding number of #'s in new lines. Example:

```
Input:
5 4 3 2 1

Output:
#####
####
###
##
#

Input:
16
0
4
12

Output:
################

####
############

Input:
1 1 3 
2 1

Output:
#
#
###
##
#
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[1000];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0){
        int i,j,a;
        for(i=0; sscanf(buffer+i,"%d%n",&a,&j)!=EOF; i+=j){
            while(a-->0){
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly fine for the first two examples, but what should I do with the third one, when inputs are in different lines? My program only outputs "#" in the third example, meaning that it only reads the first line of the output.

Comment: Inside a loop `scanf("%d",%x);` would work fine . As soon as new line in encountered `fgets` will return. Or else to read line by line put `fgets` inside a `while` loop.

Comment: You could call `fgets` more than once? `fgets` reads one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is to read a line input number,and then `printf` the number of `#`.You just call `fgets` once,so it only reads the first line of the input.You can use `while` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char buffer[1000];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0){
        int i,j,a;
        for(i=0; sscanf(buffer+i,"%d%n",&a,&j)!=EOF; i+=j){
            while(a-->0){
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way,`scanf` is just for learning,it have little usefull in real programe,so do not spent to much time in it.

Comment: `fgets` will return `NULL` on error or EOF , so instead of comparing with `0` use `NULL`. And instead of comparing `sscanf`'s return with `EOF`, you could use the number of arguments it correctly matches . So it could be `sscanf(...) == 2;`

Comment: @ameyCU "it could be `sscanf(...) == 1;`"  `"%n"` does not contribute to the return value.

Comment: Although OP mentioned numeric input, with non-numeric import this answer will exhibit undefined behavior (UB): (`j` used before iniitalized).  Recommend `sscanf(buffer+i,"%d %n",&a,&j) == 1`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `fgets` and then `sscanf`, you can just use `fscanf/scanf` in a `while` loop.

```
int main(){
    int a;
    while ( fscanf(stdin, "%d", &a) == 1 )
    {
       while(a-- > 0){
          printf("*");
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```